# How to pass custom props to Material-UI component using makeStyles/withStyles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

How can I pass a custom props to MUI component? Let's say I want pass `customProps='red'` which changes the background color of a component?

In my case I need to add a different background color for a button and I want to add something like this:

```
<SubmitButton
  variant={"outlined"}
  customBackground={'red'} // this prop
>
  Submit
</SubmitButton>
```

Should I use `makeStyles`?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bartik-3mf4r?file=/src/App.tsx)'s the codesandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your styles defined with `withStyles`

```
root: {
  backgroundColor: (props) => props.customBackground
  {...}
},
```

Then in the component created by `withStyles` HOC:

```
<SubmitButton customBackground="red"
```

If you want to set a group of style properties, you can pass a callback that returns a style object instead of a value ([docs](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-rule-value-function?v=v10.8.1#function-rules)):

```
root: ({ mode }) => ({
  ...(mode === "dark" && {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    color: "lightgray",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "darkblue"
    }
  }),
  ...(mode === "light" && {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    color: "black",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "lightblue"
    }
  }),
})
```

Then pass the prop in your custom component to apply dynamic styles:

```
<SubmitButton mode="light">light</SubmitButton>
<SubmitButton mode="dark">dark</SubmitButton>
```

> Should I use makeStyles?

`makeStyles` and `withStyles` are the same except that `makeStyles` returns a hook which cannot be used in a class component. If you use functional component, you should use `makeStyles` because it's more pluggable (easier to add or remove styles).

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. One more question, how can I add a set of specific properties? Let's say I want a reset button have a different color, hover and etc. I can do it the way you wrote...but is it ok or is there a more correct way? I mean how to define 'variant' with a bunch of props and assing it to button

Comment: @qweezz see my updated answer and the codesandbox, you can actually do that the easier way.